# How to get HTTP request and response from WebSocket connection

Tags: ajax, node.js, websocket, passport.js

Currently, we are using a fairly standard setup with Node.js + Passport + AJAX as the webserver, Backbone on the client, and an app server exposing APIs for the back-end.  The client makes AJAX request to Node, which does some housecleaning such as checking the session authentication, then passes the request along to the app server.

We are experimenting with replacing the AJAX portion between the client and Node with WebSockets.  That part I have working fine.  Previously we were using passport to check if the request was authenticated.  With a standard Node route, the request and response is always included so this is a trivial task, but I'm not sure how to get it from the socket.

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
var io = socketio.listen(server);
var namespaced = io.of('/socket/test');
namespaced.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected to /socket/test');

    socket.on('fetch', function (args) {
        // the client has sent a socket message which will functionally replace an AJAX request
        // authenticate session here - how to get the request??
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the socket event be `'data'`. Something like socket.on('data',function (args){   })

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's just the name of the event chosen by the developer.  It can be 'foobar' if you want it to be, it just needs to match the name of the event on the client.